# Build an Expression Tree for Entity Framework Many to Many relationship?

Tags: entity-framework, linq, linq-to-sql, many-to-many, expression-trees

I'm  working on a Code for the following structure:
3 Tables

> Table "Book", "BookAuthor" and "Author".

I now want to build up an ExpressionTree to get the following Linq-result:

```
_ent.Book.Where(c => c.BookAuthor.Any(cd => cd.Author.AuthorName == "test"));
```

My Problem is the last Expression to get to `cd.Author.AuthorName` (or similar).

 
My current code:

```
private MethodCallExpression BuiltMethodCall(IQueryable _query, string CustTypeID, Type _ParentObjType,
Type _ChildObjType, string strChildObj, string strChildCol)
    {

        //This function will build a dynamic linq expression tree representing the ling calls of:
        //Book.Where(c => c.BookAuthor.Any(cd => cd.Author = custTypeID))

        ConstantExpression value = Expression.Constant(CustTypeID);

        //Build the outer part of the Where clause
        ParameterExpression parameterOuter = Expression.Parameter(_ParentObjType, "c");
        MemberExpression propertyOuter = Expression.Property(parameterOuter, strChildObj);

        //Build the comparison inside of the Any clause
        ParameterExpression parameterInner = Expression.Parameter(_ChildObjType, "cd");
        MemberExpression propertyInner = Expression.Property(parameterInner, strChildCol);

        BinaryExpression comparison = Expression.Equal(propertyInner, value);
        LambdaExpression lambdaInner = Expression.Lambda(comparison, parameterInner);

        //Create Generic Any Method
        Func<MethodInfo, bool> methodLambda = m => m.Name == "Any" && m.GetParameters().Length == 2;
        MethodInfo method = typeof(Enumerable).GetMethods().Where(methodLambda).Single()
            .MakeGenericMethod(_ChildObjType);

        //Create the Any Expression Tree and convert it to a Lambda
        MethodCallExpression callAny = Expression.Call(method, propertyOuter, lambdaInner);
        LambdaExpression lambdaAny = Expression.Lambda(callAny, parameterOuter);

        //Build the final Where Call
        MethodCallExpression whereCall = Expression.Call(typeof(Queryable), "Where",
            new Type[] { _query.ElementType }, new Expression[]
            {
                    _query.Expression,
                    Expression.Quote(lambdaAny)
            });

        return whereCall;
    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understand correctly, you are asking how to create nested property accessor expression.

It's quite easy with the help of [`String.Split`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.string.split(v=vs.110).aspx) and [`Enumerable.Aggregate`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb549218(v=vs.110).aspx) methods.

Here is a custom extension method which can be used as `Expression.Property` method replacement:

```
public static partial class ExpressionExtensions
{
    public static MemberExpression Property(this Expression instance, string path)
    {
        return (MemberExpression)path.Split('.').Aggregate(instance, Expression.Property);
    }
}
```

It handles correctly both simple and nested properties encoded in `string` with `.` separator (e.g. `"BookAuthor"` or `"Author.AuthorName"`).

So instead of

```
MemberExpression propertyOuter = Expression.Property(parameterOuter, strChildObj);
```

and

```
MemberExpression propertyInner = Expression.Property(parameterInner, strChildCol);
```

you can safely use

```
MemberExpression propertyOuter = parameterOuter.Property(strChildObj);
```

and

```
MemberExpression propertyInner = parameterInner.Property(strChildCol);
```